# Is there something in flexbox so that when the children of the container overflow the container they go to another line?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent container:

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  display: flex;
}
```

inside it I have 2 divs, which have the same size and are always on the same line.

```
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  min-width:300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

each child div has these properties.

the `min-width` of each div is `300px`, so when the screen is very small and the `divs` overflow in width to the parent container, I would like the `div` that exceeds the width of the parent to be displayed below the other.

I think the solution would be done with a `mediaquery`, but maybe there is another more optimal solution from `flexbox` and that is why I have asked this question(for example with `flex-wrap` I achieve that the div that exceeds the width of the parent, is put underneath, but it is no longer on the same line when the resolution is large). Thank you very much

.flex-container {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 2px solid silver;
display: flex;
}

this is my full code:

```
<div class="flex-container ">
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam expedita excepturi dolor iusto et architecto, repellat fugit quisquam reprehenderit recusandae alias ut, magni quis cumque earum at laborum, consectetur voluptas.</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam expedita excepturi dolor iusto et architecto, repellat fugit quisquam reprehenderit recusandae alias ut, magni quis cumque earum at laborum, consectetur voluptas.</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2x8yLhu0/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vqzLgk1c/

Comment: @sol  what does flex: 0 mean?  `flex: 1 0 300px;` put your answer please

Answer (score 1):

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  min-width:300px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 0;
}
```

You can add the flex-wrap:wrap in the container class.
but in this case, you should add it in flex-item class;

Comment: what does `flex: 0` mean?

Comment: flex: 0 means that flex-shrink : 1, flex-basis: 0. the flex shrink factor is multiplied by the flex basis when distributing negative space. so width = flex-shrink * flex-basis.

Comment: so flex: 0 same as width: auto. but In flexbox, width is not working well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to `.flex-container`.

Then you probably want to add a `max-width` to `.flex-item` or else the boxes will forever be on top of each other as they expand the full width.

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid silver;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap:wrap; /* Add this so they go on top of each other */
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* Center boxes, evenly spaced out in div */
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  min-width:300px;
  max-width:500px; /* Add this so they don't stretch full width */
  margin: 10px;
}
```